# WHERE for a single column on a JOIN?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL statement that's working with one exception.

```
RewardSQL = "SELECT tblMembers.ID, Max(tblRewards.IssueDate) AS LastReward, Last(tblRewards.IssueAmount) AS LastRewardAmount FROM tblMembers INNER JOIN tblRewards ON tblMembers.ID = tblRewards.CustomerID GROUP BY tblMembers.ID HAVING ((([Forms]![frmRewards]![txtID]) = [tblMembers]![ID])) "
DoCmd.SearchForRecord , "", acFirst, "[ID] = " & Str(Nz(Screen.ActiveControl, 0))
DoCmd.Requery "lstCustomers"
```

I'm trying to get the MAX of Issue Date, which is working, and the most recent Issue Amount, which isn't.

Neither LAST nor MAX is giving me the most recent $$ for the query.  It's giving me the highest amount.

I figured I could accomplish it with a WHERE clause, but I'm just not sure where to put it.

Ideas?  Thanks!

EDIT:
Example data:

```
IssueDate     IssueAmount
4/1            5.00
4/2            4.00
4/3            3.00
4/4            2.00
4/5            1.00
```

Currently the statement is pulling the highest date (4/5) and the highest amount (5.00).  I need to pull the highest date (4/5) and the most recent amount (1.00).

Comment: Can you share some example data, and desired output? (In TEXT, not in PICTURES  )

Comment: Did you read the remarks in the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/first-last-functions-acd76019-c37f-432d-9807-4fc63cac1db5):  "These functions return the value of a specified field in the first or last record, respectively, of the result set returned by a query. If the query does not include an ORDER BY clause, the values returned by these functions will be arbitrary because records are usually returned in no particular order."  ?    You do not have an `ORDER BY`, so te return value for LAST() will be _arbitrary_.

Comment: Why yes, yes I did read the remarks.  That's why I said neither MAX nor LAST gives me the desired output.  My concern with ORDER BY is the exact same as my original question - how/where/what.  How does it work with a JOIN, where does it go in a statement with a JOIN, and what should I ORDER BY?  Date?  Amount?  ID? Something else?  I'm not an SQL master, and was hoping for some help from those who are SQL masters.

Comment: see my answer. which simply first finds the MAX, and then selects the record where the date is equal to that MAX-value.

Answer (score 1):

This query might do it (but I do not have clue how to do that in ms-access):

```
SELECT
   tblMembers.ID, 
   tblRewards.IssueDate,
   tblRewards.IssueAmount
FROM tblMembers 
INNER JOIN tblRewards ON tblMembers.ID = tblRewards.CustomerID 
WHERE tblRewards.IssueDate = (
   SELECT
      Max(tblRewards.IssueDate) AS LastReward
   FROM tblMembers 
   INNER JOIN tblRewards ON tblMembers.ID = tblRewards.CustomerID)
```

Comment: I have it all plugged in and running, and I can't tell if it's working because it broke another line of code (making me think the HAVING is required?).  I'll add that piece of code to the original post.

Comment: When this change cause a brake in another line of code, it might be cause my the missing aliased to `LastReward` and `LastRewardAmount` ?

Comment: This fires back two results.  One result is correct, and the other is (presumably) the MAX or LAST of all entries in tblRewards - even if it's not the CustomerID in question.

Is there an issue because I don't have the "HAVING" clause?

Comment: You only need a `HAVING` clause when you use a `GROUP BY`, which is not present in y answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you want the amount on the most recent date.  If you order the query by `IssueDate` descending, the record you want should be the first (`TOP`) row.

```sql
SELECT TOP 1
    m.ID,
    r.IssueDate,
    r.IssueAmount
FROM
    tblMembers AS m
    INNER JOIN tblRewards AS r
    ON m.ID = r.CustomerID
WHERE m.ID = [Forms]![frmRewards]![txtID]
ORDER BY r.IssueDate DESC
```

However, I don't see why you need to join those 2 tables since all the information you need is in `tblRewards`

```sql
SELECT TOP 1
    r.CustomerID,
    r.IssueDate,
    r.IssueAmount
FROM
    tblRewards AS r
WHERE r.CustomerID = [Forms]![frmRewards]![txtID]
ORDER BY r.IssueDate DESC
```

Comment: The first example returns the most recent Issue Date and the most recent issue amount and date of that amount from tblRewards.  Not the most recent entry from the CustomerID.

ID-Correct, IssueDate-incorrect, IssueAmount-incorrect.  Both of those it's pulling the top/max/last entry in the table.

Comment: `Not the most recent entry from the CustomerID`? What does this mean? Does it mean the most recent entry from the tblMembers table? does that table have a 'date' column to apply the 'most recent' criteria? The only date column you mentioned is tblRewards.IssueDate